# Problems with mouseleave/focusout event handlers and user selecting from autocomplete list

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, settimeout, jquery-events

I have bound the jQuery event handler `mouseover` to an element with the below code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    
    jQuery('#buyout_field').mouseleave(function() {
        alert('Hi!');
    });    

});
```

This works great, but then I noticed that if the user selects a value from those dropdown `auto-complete` menus the browser shows you of your past data you have entered that the `mouseleave` event fires too early for my liking. Yes, it fires at the right time (when their mouse leaves the element); however I need the function to fire only after the user has entered data into the field.

I then added the `focusout` handler to cover more bases with:

```
jQuery('#buyout_field').focusout(function() {
    alert('Hi!');
});
```

However it's still possible the user may select a value from the dropdown list AND not click outside the text field.

Do I have any other options here at firing the function or do I have to resort to perhaps using `setTimeout()` to allow the user time to select something from the autocomplete list and THEN fire the function OR should I just disable autocomplete?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wbsDy/

Comment: What does those dropdowns look like? if it's just regular select elements you're doing it all wrong and should be using the `change` event!

Comment: Could you please post a fiddle?

Comment: @adeneo No, not select elements; the auto-complete ones. Like say you're entering your email into a email address field, once you click your mouse in it it will usually show a dropdown list of former email addresses you have entered previously so you don't have to type it again.

Comment: You would just use the change event for that as well, as any action will blur the input and fire the change event if the value changed, you don't use mouse events for that.

Comment: @DevlshOne Posted a fiddle.

Comment: @adeneo So you're saying I should also bind an onchange event handler to the element?

Comment: You don't have the autocomplete in the fiddle.

Comment: @DevlshOne I'm not sure what u mean? The browser itself controls that based on your past entries..... which is why I called the field email as I thought you would have previous entries for that in the browser.